# Pyspark - remove multiple items from array column

Tags: python, pyspark

pyspark provides array_remove(column: Column, element: Any) function that returns the column after removing all values that are equal to the element. 
Example from AIP documents:

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([([1, 2, 3, 1, 1],), ([],)], ['data'])
>>> df.select(array_remove(df.data, 1)).collect()
[Row(array_remove(data, 1)=[2, 3]), Row(array_remove(data, 1)=[])]
```

I was wondering if there is any straight forward way (except doing a simple for loop) to use this function for removing multiple elements (provided in a list) from the column.

Note: as pointed out by jxc, one can use the array_except() method. However, for my usecase I need to keep the items of the array in the same order after filtering and when I tested with array_except, the order was not maintained.

Comment: use array_except()?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately for my usecase the problem with this approach is that the order of items are not maintained after filtering using array_except. I updated the question to add this constraint.

Comment: use filter:  `expr('filter(data, x -> !array_contains(col_excluded, x))')` where col_excluded is a column containing list of items to be removed.  array_except has side-effects of de-duplicated the resulting list.